# How to integrated javascript /web 3 into wordpress?

Tags: web3js, javascript, dapps

hello everyone i use wordpress for website developement and right now i developping a web3 app and i would to know how can i integrated the script to wordpress element (button etc ).

Should i develop only in html ?